# Count number of records by date

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Given this model:

```
Foo(models.Model):
    some_fields
        ...
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to show the data in a graph where X axis is time (HH:MM) and Y axis is the number of instances at that time.

I've tried this:

```
Foo.objects.extra({'date_created' : "date(date)"}).annotate(created_count=Count('id')).values('date_created', 'created_count')
```

But the value of *created_count* is always 1, even if I create 2 instances at the same time (bulk_create).

Any idea to accomplish this in Django 1.8?

**UPDATE:** Since the field DateTimeField stores the milliseconds, the query doesn't count the records of the same day *and* time as if they were created at the same time, so I finally settled to zero the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to order it before annotating it. Only *one* answer on stackoverflow mentioned this, so here you go.

```
Foo.objects.extra({'date_created' : "date(date)"}).order_by("date_created").annotate(created_count=Count('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the `annotate` in the wrong order with `values` and taken the wrong count of column. The way you have chained in

```
Foo.objects.extra(
  {'date_created' : "date(date)"}
).annotate(created_count=Count('id')).values('date_created', 'created_count')`
```

annotates the count grouped by all the columns in the table, which therefore gives count as 1.

**Solution**:

```
Foo.objects.extra(
  {'date_created' : "date(date)"}
).values('date_created').annotate(created_count=Count('date'))
```

This first selects `date` as `date_created`, then take `count` grouped by date.